# Error:(415, 32) return (Float)Math.sqrt (x * x + y * y);

Tags: android

I use for determine the space between the first two fingers Android SDK 23 marshmallow

```
     private float spacing(WrapMotionEvent event) {
         // ...
         float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (Float)Math.sqrt (x * x + y * y);
    }
```

warning message

> Error:(415, 32) error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.sqrt` returns a `double`, even if the input is `float`.

You can't convert `double` to `Float` (the wrapper type) other than explicitly going via `float` (the primitive type)... but that's okay, because you don't actually *want* `Float`. The return type of your method is `float`, so just cast to that instead:

```
return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

If the return type of your method *had* been `Float`, you could still use the same line of code, and let the compiler add auto-boxing from `float` to `Float`.